# new BehaviorSubject returning Null Id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs

i'am in the process of creating a shoping cart but i have this weird probleme were the Id of the basket always null
basket.ts

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export interface IBasket {
  id: string;
  items: IBasketItem[];
}

export interface IBasketItem {
  id: number;
  productName: string;
  price: number;
  quantity: number;
  pictureUrl: string;
  brand: string;
  type: string;
}

export class Basket implements IBasket {
  id: string = uuidv4();
  items: IBasketItem[] = [];
}
```

basket service

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, map } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Basket, IBasket, IBasketItem } from '../shared/Models/basket';
import { IProduct } from '../shared/Models/product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BasketService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;

  private basketSource = new BehaviorSubject<IBasket>(null);
  basket$ = this.basketSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getBasket(id: string) {
    return this.http.get<IBasket>(this.baseUrl + 'basket?id=' + id).pipe(
      map((basket: IBasket) => {
        this.basketSource.next(basket);
      })
    );
  }
  setBasket(basket: IBasket) {
    return this.http.post<IBasket>(this.baseUrl + 'basket', basket).subscribe(
      (response: IBasket) => this.basketSource.next(response),
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
  getCurrentBasketValue() {
    return this.basketSource.getValue();
  }

  addItemToBasket(item: IProduct, quantity = 1) {
    const itemToAdd: IBasketItem = this.mapProductItemToBasketItem(
      item,
      quantity
    );

    const basket = this.getCurrentBasketValue() ?? this.createBasket();

    basket.items = this.addOrUpdateItem(basket.items, itemToAdd, quantity);
    console.log(basket);
    // this.setBasket(basket);
  }
  private addOrUpdateItem(
    items: IBasketItem[],
    itemToAdd: IBasketItem,
    quantity: number
  ): IBasketItem[] {
    const index = items.findIndex((i) => i.id === itemToAdd.id);
    if (index === -1) {
      itemToAdd.quantity = quantity;
      items.push(itemToAdd);
    } else {
      items[index].quantity += quantity;
    }
    return items;
  }
  private createBasket(): IBasket {
    const basket = new Basket();
    console.log('ezeze');
    localStorage.setItem('basket_id', basket.id);
    return basket;
  }
  private mapProductItemToBasketItem(
    item: IProduct,
    quantity: number
  ): IBasketItem {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      productName: item.name,
      price: item.price,
      pictureUrl: item.pictureUrl,
      quantity,
      brand: item.productBrand,
      type: item.productType,
    };
  }
}
```

product-item.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BasketService } from 'src/app/basket/basket.service';
import { IProduct } from 'src/app/shared/Models/product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-item',
  templateUrl: './product-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-item.component.scss'],
})
export class ProductItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product: IProduct;

  constructor(private basketService: BasketService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  addItemToBasket() {
    this.basketService.addItemToBasket(this.product);
  }
}
```

product-item.html

```
<div class="card h-100 shadow-sm">
  <div class="image position-relative" style="cursor: pointer">
    <img
      src="{{ product.pictureUrl }}"
      alt="{{ product.name }}"
      srcset=""
      class="img-fluid bg-light"
    />
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center hover-overlay">
      <button
        (click)="addItemToBasket()"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-secondary fa fa-shopping-cart me-2"
      ></button>

      <button
        routerLink="/shop/{{ product.id }}"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-secondary"
      >
        view
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column">
    <a routerLink="/shop/{{ product.id }}">
      <h6 class="text-uppercase">{{ product.name }}</h6>
    </a>
    <span class="mb-2">{{ product.price | currency }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

so basically the problem appears when i click on a product the id of of the basket is always null
the items are adding up but the Id is null

ex:{
**"id": "null",**
"items": [
{
"id": 8788,
"productName": "T Blues",
"price": 20,
"pictureUrl": "*********/images/products/bo.png",
"quantity": 1,
"brand": "Y",
"type": "Z"
}
]
}

any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Are you getting the basket from an API call?  If so does the response of that API call have a value for the basket ID?

Comment: you need to tell us if you are getting the `id` in the component . Also , on which like you see it as null , otherwise it is impossible to debug properly

Comment: i'am generating the Id with uuid  the thing is `private basketSource = new BehaviorSubject<IBasket>(null);this.basketSource.getValue()` always return null in console.log like this {
    "id": "null",
    "items": []
}

Answer (score 0):

The `BehaviorSubject` returns the last item sent to it.

you are initializing it with a `null`:

```js
(...)
  export class BasketService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
//                                                     \/  here     
  private basketSource = new BehaviorSubject<IBasket>(null);
```

so the first time you subscribe to its value, it will yield `null`

I don't see a call to `getBasket` on your component, it might not have been called... or the service might not have responded in time to provide the next value into `basketSource`

also [BehaviorSubject's](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) are better used as Observables, to avoid issues with its value.

you should remove the function

```
getCurrentBasketValue() {
    return this.basketSource.getValue();
  }
```

make the prop `basketSource` public and get its value filtering out nulls when needed as the following:

```
basketService.basketSource.pipe(filter(x=>x), take(1)).subscribe(source => {
  // your code here, 

})
```

Comment: but normally it shoud get it initial values from Basket class wich initial values are `export class Basket implements IBasket {
  id: string = uuidv4();
  items: IBasketItem[] = [];
}` that's the confusing part